# Is it better to store the magnitude of an arbitrary-precision number in BigEndian or LittleEndian order in an integer array?

Tags: data-structures, arrays

I'm implementing a class which provides arbitrary-precision arithmetic (also called "bignum", "BigInteger", etc.).

My questions is about a practical implementation detail:

I'm wondering if there is a significant difference in implementation and computational complexity between an implementation which stores the magnitude in an integer array in BigEndian order vs. LittleEndian order.

My data structure is basically:

```
class BigInt
  val signum: Int
  val magnitude: Array[Int] // two-complement (unsigned)
```

Supported operations are for instance:

+, -, * (Long multiplication, Karatsuba, Cook3, Schönhage-Strassen), /, squaring
Conversion to other number types
Comparison, equality, representation as a String

*The implementation is immutable, so every operation will return a new value and will not change the any existing.*

Feel free to ask for clarifications!

Comment: Welcome! If I understand it correctly, the question is essentially an implementation question. Maybe it should be on [so]?

Comment: [Big-endian vs little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_and_operating_systems_on_architectures) is the quintessential debate over something that doesn't matter. What kind of difference do you think it might make?

Answer (score 5):

You are replacing `magnitude[i]` by `magnitude[SZ-i]`. That won't have any effect on complexity nor ease of implementation. Depending on the way simplifications occur, one or the other could have slightly less index adjustments, but I won't dare a guess which. Little endian seems slightly more in line with the usual presentations of the algorithms (for instance in TAOCP), big endian had a more intuitive representation of the number in memory, but that's an opinion more than a fact.

If you look at memory access patterns, there was a time when cache prefiller handled better increasing consecutive accesses (which would have favored little endian), but nowadays, I don't think it still make a difference at least on workstation and server processors.

So I don't think there is a compelling argument to choose BE over LE or ortherwise. Take the one which make you more at ease.

Comment: Regarding cache prefill, it depends on the processor type. I believe current ARM processors don't do any useful prefetch with decreasing addresses, wherean Intel processors do.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of computational complexity, and even in terms of significant differences in running time, it doesn't matter. Pick one.

From a software engineering perspective, having recently debugged bignum code on architectures with different endiannesses, I've found a big-endian representation easier to work with because I can read numbers straight out of a hexadecimal memory dump (i.e. when I see `000700123456789abc` in a memory dump, I can copy-paste `123456789abc` to check the value in a calculator). This is not a compelling argument, and only applies if your debugging tools aren't capable of recognizing bignums as such.